# jQuery .load not able to read declared variables?

Tags: php, ajax, variables

I have my main file where all my variables are declared. I have a second file that gets loaded into the main file with $.load after a button is clicked.

But the file that gets loaded in has variables that are declared inside the main file. Example:

Main file:

```
$account_name = <?php get_option('account_name'); ?>
$account_pass = <?php get_option('account_pass'); ?>
```

Secondary File that is loaded into the main file

```
 // check if variable is set
 <script>alert(<?php echo $account_name; ?>);</script>
 (returns undefined)

 $url = 'http://www.somewebsite.com/' . $account_name . '/page-4/'
```

But as you can see it is not sure what $account_name is set too, and if I try and redeclare the variables inside the secondary file, I am unable to .load it and receive a 500 error.

I tried to check the variable in an alert inside the secondary file but it just returns as undefined.

How can I go about declaring the variables in the secondary file? I've been trying for a little while with an ajax post/get to try and pass the variable to that file, but haven't had much luck with that. The variable just returns undefined.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Could you share a little bit more of your code?

Comment: What else do you want me to share? I've posted how I've declared the variables, how they are loaded into one another etc. Both files are exceptionally long

Comment: post js code that has been generated by your php script

Comment: I'm not sure that I fully understand your problem. Are you trying to access PHP variables inside PHP code using jQuery's `load()`? If so, that's not what `load()` does.

Comment: Is `$account_name` a PHP or JavaScript variable?  Your "main" file, what is that?  A PHP file, HTML file, JavaScript file?  How are these 2 files "linked"?

Comment: since you do not use any kind of char escaping, it is highly likely you have JS errors

Comment: I am loading in a php file to my main file using .load, which references variables that were set inside of the main file. All files are php files. $account_name is a php variable

Answer (score 0):

Variables are set on a per-HTTP-request basis. When you use JavaScript to load a different HTTP resource, then PHP variables are not going to persist.

Pass the data in the query string or use sessions.